# how to disable Empathy notifications in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, empathy, notification

in 12.10 there was a tab on preferences of empathy that i could configure notifications in empathy and now in 13.04 it's not available anymore

so is there any way to disable the notifications or the balloons ??

Answer (score 2):

You can disable using dconf editor.

Go to:

org > gnome > empathy > notifications

and disable the keys "notifications-enable" and "notifications-focus". It worked to me in Ubuntu 13.04.