# Disable Bubble notifications in Empathy using Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: empathy, notification

How do I Disable Bubble notifications in Empathy using Ubuntu 13.04? There are a couple threads out there like this one:

[how to disable Empathy notifications in ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292158/how-to-disable-empathy-notifications-in-ubuntu-13-04)

but there isn't an org directory anywhere I can find. The notification options were removed in empathy's preferences, so that won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292158/how-to-disable-empathy-notifications-in-ubuntu-13-04) says *"org > gnome > empathy > notifications"* it means the schema in dconf-editor.

### Disable Empathy notifications With Dconf-Editor

Make sure you have dconf-tool installed.

**1)** Open a Terminal window and type:

- `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

**2)** Go to the dash home and search for the ***"dconf-editor"*** to open it

[image]

**3)** Navigate to the **org.gnome.empathy.notifications** and uncheck the key **"notifications-enabled"**

[image]

### Disable Empathy notifications With gsettings command

If you prefer... you can do it with one command.

**1)** Open a Terminal window and just type:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.Empathy.notifications notifications-enabled false`

Hope it helps.

Comment: No effect in ubuntu 12.04. `notify-send "test"` still appears

Comment: that's because this is for Empathy only... unfortunately.